# How to not finish activity when the phone call arrived android?

Tags: android

Hello friends, 
              I want to make the application in such when the any call(PHONE CALL) on my device than my current activity should not finish..As we see that whenever phone call arrived to our phone than our current activity of our device become hide and than call screen appears.So friends i want to implement such a application that whenever the device phone arrived than our current activity **SHOULD NOT** disappears..Please help me to short out from these problem..Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question **No it is not possible to do this without OEM/framework support. This is done from the Phone app.**

**Next:** The current activity is not finished rather is sent to background and once the call is over, it comes up to foreground once again.

**How the entire call flow works ?**

The telephony layer (referring to the framework opt telephony module) receives a message for an incoming call. This message is processed and is passed on with the change in state to the receivers which are listening for this event. Now the Phone app (system or 3rd party) receives this information and launches a full screen intent using the notification manager. Once this happens the activity takes up the entire screen.

The system Phone app set the *InCallScreen* to have window flags which enables them to come above `KEYGUARD`. Additionally the system `Phone app` disables the **HOME, BACK & RECENT** buttons. These are enabled after the state of the InCallScreen has been changed something other than **RINGING**

**I was just wondering why do you want to do this ?** This is in violation of the guidelines and also this is not a good user experience.

Additionally if you look at the new Lollipop update this is completely NOT required. With Android 5.x this entire thing has been done away with. InComing call is shown as a notification and does not hinder the user to continue any ongoing task/activity.

Please go through the android source code to understand this better

Comment: thanks bro for yours valueable answer..
I want to ask that when i receive the call when i doing anything on my device than my current sreen should not hide.Instead it shown at the bottom of the screen..

Comment: not possible to have this before Android 5.0. Your issue is actually the intended behavior and cannot be tweaked

Comment: bro are you totally sure that it can not be tweaked before 5.0 versions

Comment: there are window layout params which can be used to bring a view come on top of everything else but then you will not be able to press back/home/recent while the phone is in ringing state, like WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG/ERROR but again they have their own issues. And once again I am pretty sure...

Comment: If you are writing a Phone application then yes